# 'Redux' is not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my HTML file:

I'm starting with React-Create-App and modifying it. Some of the files are installed locally while Redux I'm trying to load in from a CDN.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.js"></script>
    <script src="fb.me/react-15.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="fb.me/react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then in my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Counter from './Counter'

const { createStore } = Redux;
const store = createStore(Counter);

const comp = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter value={0}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)}

comp()
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
  Line 19:  'Redux' is not defined  no-undef
```

It works in Jsbin, but I can't get it to work on sublime. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to  import `createStore` from `redux` after installing it with npm

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```

Comment: @MorganAllen, one more thing, prefer not to use cdn , you should gowith webpack

Comment: yea, trying to figure out how to update my package.json to include redux. Also I'm now getting the error: `TypeError: createStore is not a function` It doesn't look like I am importing creatStore correct?

Comment: npm install -S 'redux'

Comment: is there a way to do it through package.json?

Comment: Add ` "redux": "^3.6.0",`  in package.json dependencies and tun `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed `npm install` to get react and all of it's dependecies? It may be a problem with that.

Comment: Yes. This works if I don't include anything from Redux